# Multiple Gtag and/or Analytics GA4 in a single page

Tags: google-analytics-4, gtag.js

we have a webapp, that we provide as whitelabel to our clients.
Each client wants to link their analytics, but we want to monitor stats as well.
I tried adding one Gtag container, and multiple GA4 analytics tags, but there are some conflict.
For instance, if in one GTAG container I add one GA4 tag for us, and one GA4 for our client,
data are tracked sometimes under our tag, sometimes under theirs...

I read that I cannot add multiple GTAG containers in the same page.
What could be the solution?

Each customer wants track data, and monitor their events etc, and we want do that as well.

Right now, this is the code used, with just 1 container

```html
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
> 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
> })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXXXXX');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```